# how to resize png image dimension in plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I've set Latex as an interpreter for plot. I've noticed that if I increase the font size, the png dimension increases ( see the below picture ). I would like to resize the png before I save it. Is there an easy solution for this problem? I've looked at the plot Editor but nothing about this feature. I have multiple images, therefore I want them to have same size.

[image]

Comment: What is your version of Matlab ?

Comment: The version is R2014a

Answer (score 0):

you can position your axes using

```
set(gca, 'position', [left bottom width height])
```

where gca is your axes handle.

e.g.

```
figure;
plot(1,1);
set(gca, 'position', [.05 0.5 .9 .9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One hack you could try is to save the figure data as an image, then crop out the unwanted columns.  Assuming that your figure is already open, you can use the `getframe` and `cdata` idiom.  However, using `cdata` will only get the image content itself.  You also need the axes as well as the labels themselves, so you'll need to capture a border around the figure as well.  To make it easy, we will do this in pixels.  Assuming your image is already open do this:

```
ax = gca; %// Get current axes
ax.Units = 'pixels'; %// Set the axes units to Pixels
pos = ax.Position; %// Get position of figure

marg = 30; %// Get 30 pixel border around main content
rect = [-marg, -marg, pos(3)+2*marg, pos(4)+2*marg]; %// Define rectangle
F = getframe(gca,rect); %// Capture figure as image

%// Reset the axes back to what they were before (normalized)
ax.Units = 'normalized';

im = F.cdata; %// Get image

%// Show the image
figure;
imshow(im);
```

This should open up a new figure where it will crop out what you don't need.